# Sobrecarga de operador unario en C++

Tags: c++

He creado la siguiente clase.

```
class Persona{

private:
    std::string nombre;

public:
    std::string getNombre();
    Persona operator=(std::string nombre);

};

Persona Persona::operator=(std::string nombre){

    Persona persona;
    persona.nombre = nombre;

    return persona;
}

std::string Persona::getNombre(){
    return this->nombre;
}
```

Como ven, se hace una sobrecarga del operador `=`:

```
Persona operator=(std::string nombre);
```

***Lo que pretendo, es poder asignar el valor al atributo `nombre` usando el operador `=`.***

Dejando mi codigo asi:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

class Persona{

private:
    std::string nombre;

public:
    std::string getNombre();
    Persona operator=(std::string nombre);

};

Persona Persona::operator=(std::string nombre){

    Persona persona;
    persona.nombre = nombre;

    return persona;
}

std::string Persona::getNombre(){
    return this->nombre;
}

int main(void)
{

    Persona p;

    p = "John Doe";

    std::cout << "Nombre: " << p.getNombre() << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Al realizar la compilacion, no hay ningun error, basado en lo que he leido, el operador `=` hace un retorno, y este se asigna al objeto donde se usa:

```
p = "John Doe";
```

Pero! Cuando ejecuto el programa, esto obtengo:

> Nombre:
>
> Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.015 s
>
> Press any key to continue.

El valor que deberia, estarse asignando, no se asigna, dejando el nombre vacio.

**¿Que error estoy cometiendo en la sobrecarga del operator = ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo correcto sería (lo muestro *inline* para abreviar):

```
class Persona{
private:
  std::string nombre;

public:
  Persona &operator=( std::string nnombre ) {
    nombre = nnombre;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Para acceder a los miembros de nuestra propia clase, no es necesario *precederlos* con el nombre de la clase; todos los miembros pasan a estar accesibles desde el cuerpo de las funciones, como si fueran variables locales de la función. Es una facilidad que le ofrece el lenguaje al programador.

Por lo mismo, tampoco es necesario acceder a ellos como `this->ALGO`; eso se utilizaría en caso de conflicto de nombres; por ejemplo, recibir un argumento del método con un mismo nombre que un atributo de la clase.

En tu código original, dentro de `operator=( )`, creas una nueva instancia de la clase `Persona`, asignas a esa instancia, y luego devuelves esa instancia que has creado. Al hacerlo así, la instancia original **queda intacta**.

Fíjate también que **he cambiado** el valor de retorno de tu `operator=`. En lugar de devolver una instancia, devuelvo **una referencia a la instancia original**.

Comment: Tienes, razon. El valor ha quedado intacto, ya he realizado los cambios que me has sugerido, funciona! Muchas gracias

Comment: Un placer :-) Y gracias por la edición de la respuesta, se me pasó el `};`